# How to compute distance between numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, math, algebra

I want to compute the distance between numbers with help of the system described in the attached image.

For example: distance between 7 and 5 is -2, distance between 7 and 1 is 2 etc...

Any ideas how to do this in c++? The prefered direction is counter clockwise...
I am using a (int) vector.

[image]

Comment: What's your data model ? A vector like [0,1,2,...,7] ?

Comment: Yes, you are right... So in your example I want to compare 0 with 1, 1 with 2 etc...

Comment: Show us what you've got, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Something is missing in your explanation:
dist(7, 5) = -2 you're counting clockwise.
dist(7, 1) = 2 you're counting counter clockwise.
Why not both clockwise?

Comment: @MikeKinghan Unfortunately, I don't know how to start...

Comment: I assume since CCW is the "preferred" direction, the distance from 0 to 4 would be 4 and not negative 4? It seems that you want to count in the shortest direction, with CCW being the direction to go in if both directions would give the same absolute distance value?

Comment: @Harper You are completely right

Comment: Look up modulo arithmetic. The C/C++ operator is `%`.

Comment: @EVERYBODY I did not expect so many awesome answers. THANK YOU ALL!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it in straightforward way (by considering all possibilities) it might look as follows

```
int distance(int a, int b)
{ // Distance from `a` to `b`
  int d = b - a;
  return
    a <= b ? 
      (d <= +4 ? d : d - 8) :
      (d <= -4 ? d + 8 : d);
}
```

which, if you prefer, can be rewritten as

```
int distance(int a, int b)
{ // Distance from `a` to `b`
  int d = b - a;
  return -4 < d && d <= 4 ? d : (d > 0 ? d - 8 : d + 8);
}
```

---

An alternative, more elegant approach would be to always calculate the positive CCW distance and flip it to negative CW distance if it is greater than 4

```
int distance(int a, int b)
{ // Distance from `a` to `b`
  int d = (b + 8 - a) % 8;
  // `d` is CCW distance from `a` to `b`
  return d <= 4 ? d : d - 8;
}
```

But if you want the compiler to generate the most efficient code for this, follow the golden rule "use unsigned types everywhere you can, use signed types only if you have to":

```
int distance(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{ // Distance from `a` to `b`
  unsigned d = (b + 8 - a) % 8;
  // `d` is CCW distance from `a` to `b`
  return d <= 4 ? d : (int) d - 8;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer! It really helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm kind of unsure what the cast to `unsigned` is supposed to achieve here.  It seems to be strictly unnecessary, given inputs that are in range.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: By using `unsigned` types we convey some critical information to the compiler. The switch to `unsigned` types allows the compiler to generate more efficient code for `(b + 8 - a) % 8` expression, since as long as the types are `unsigned`, the semantics of this expression is equivalent to your `(b - a) & 7`. GCC, for one example, generates the same code for both as long as I use `unsigned` types. Semantics of `signed` types under division is sufficiently different, which leads to more complicated and less efficient machine code.

Comment: In general, `unsigned` arithmetic is more efficient than signed one. In this case I use `unsigned` types to achieve the efficiency of `(b - a) & 7` without having to resort to bit-hacking at the level of source code. The basic principle is simple: the more information you supply the compiler with, the better code it will be able to generate. So, no, it is not an "optimization" at all. It is just a good programming practice, that often produces more efficient code as a side-effect.

Answer (score 3):

These are really complicated answers.  Here is a simpler one:

```
int distance(int x, int y) {
    int d = (y - x) & 7;
    return d > 4 ? d - 8 : d;
}
```

This always returns a result in the range -3..+4.  Modular arithmetic is a little simpler to write when the ring size is a power of two, as is the case here.

```
distance(7, 5) = -2
distance(5, 7) = +2
distance(6, 2) = +4
distance(2, 6) = +4
```

We use `& 7` because it is the simplest way to get the modulo.  Alternatively, you can use `% 8`, but you must also add 8 in order to make sure that the input is not negative:

```
int d = (y - x + 8) % 8; // same result
```

Alternatively, you can handle negative numbers explicitly:

```
int d = (y - x) % 8;
if (d < 0) {
    d += 8;
}
// same result
```

This is just a matter of style.

Comment: Awesome, I really like this clever answer!

Comment: As far as I see this code covers all requirements and is extremely short, great :)

Comment: @Engo: The code does cover all requirements, but unnecessarily relies on the binary representation used by the underlying platform. The equivalence of `& 7` to `% 8` for negative numbers is not guaranteed by the language, even though it will work on overwhelming majority of platforms.

Comment: @AnT Is there a way to improve this code and keep it short?

Comment: @Engo: Um... The code in this answer is 1-to-1 equivalent of the code in my answer. The only difference is that I used `int d = (b + 8 - a) % 8;`, while this answer uses `int d = (y - x) & 7;`. The latter is a "hackish" was to implement the same thing. My variant is like 3 characters longer. Doesn't it "keep it short" as well?

Comment: @AnT Yes, it is also short. Both of your answers were really helpful. It's hard to select the best answer :(.

Comment: Maybe, I should wait a bit to see what people think?

Comment: @AnT: Let's not devolve into pedantry here.  No sane person wants to write code that works on all possible standards-conformant C implementations, that's just a waste of time.  All modern systems are twos-complement.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: You are turning it upside down. It is actually the other way around: no sane person wants to write hackish platform-dependent code, when regular straightforward platform-agnostic arithmetic solves the problem just as well. In the case there's no reason to use code that cares about signed representation of the underlying platform (even if all of them a 2's-complement).

Comment: @AnT: Are you saying that you are actually, truly worried that your code might run on a system that is not twos-complement?

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Where? No, I'm not. I'm just abhorred by manual division/multiplication optimizations in situations when the divisor/multiplier is a *compile time constant* (!).

Comment: @AnT: That's not an optimization.  It's just a simpler way of writing the same code.  The fact that it happens to be optimized is a happy coincidence.

Comment: @AnT: There are basically three alternatives here.  You mask the bits, you use the modulo and handle the negative case, or you use the modulo and cast to unsigned.  Considering the three cases, that all give the same answer, masking is the simplest.

Comment: @AnT: The fact that you find something like this "abhorrent" is a matter of style.  It's hardly worth arguing this fervently about.  I find it abhorrent to cast numbers to `unsigned` when it's not necessary, but it would be tasteless to comment about it on your question, again, because it's just a matter of style.

Comment: Very interesting to hear your disagreements. I will take a look at the execution time of both solutions, since it's part of a bigger image processing application. I am curious which one is gonna be faster...

Comment: @Engo: Compare the assembly generated first, since if it is the same there is no point in timing it.  You might also want to look at changing the last line to `return d - (((d - 1) & 4) << 1);` which is branchless.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can find the element from [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and get the distance from start from [std::distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/)

for example 
as you mentioned the data saved in int vector

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), val_1);
std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), val_2);

int dist = std::distance(myvec.begin(),it1) - std::distance(myvec.begin.it2);
if(dist < 0) return dist
else(dist > 0) return myvector.size() - dist()
```

So hope this will give the distance as the image ...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this works:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
distance(x,y) {
    a = y-x
    b = length(list)-abs(y-x)
    z = min(abs(a), abs(b))
    if(z=abs(a)) { return a }
    if(z=abs(b)) { return b }
}
```

where `abs()` is the mathematical absolute value function.

I make a few assumptions here.

1. As @Hédi Ghédiri pointed out, you are not counting counter-clockwise both times. I am assuming you count the shortest path to the number. (I used the mathematical `min()` function)
2. You prefer the positive value over the negative value (@Harper's comment). If you prefer the negative value, switch the last two `if` statements.

There may be a more concise method, but this (hopefully) works. Please comment if it is wrong. Hope this is helpful!

Edit: this is psuedocode. It should be easy to write in c++. Use the `abs()` function in `<stdlib.h>` Forget about `list` and `length(list)`. Use `int` types for the variables, and everything else should work.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome explanation your pseudo code!

Answer (score 1):

The following code is prepared to meet all of your needs, for example I assume, that if direction is clockwise the distance is to be negative.

```
#include <iostream>

#define RING_SIZE 8

enum direction
{
    clockwise,
    counterClockwise
};

int distance(int a, int b, direction dir)
{
    int dist;
    if(dir == clockwise)
    {
        if(a>b)
        {
            dist = -(a-b); 
        }
        else
        {
            dist =-(RING_SIZE-b+a); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(a<b)
        {
            dist = b-a; 
        }
        else
        {
            dist = RING_SIZE-a+b; 
        }

    }
    if(a==b) dist = 0;//Add this if distance between same point must to be 0
    return dist;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << distance(7, 2, clockwise) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this should work

```
int func(a,b)
{
    dist=(b-a);
    if(dist<0) 
      dist +=8;
    return dist;

}
```

in case you're really stuck

Comment: @Timothy Higinbottom: Well, it actually works fine for `func(0,4)` and returns `4`. But it does not meet the other requirements.

Comment: @AnT: True, sorry about that; my mistake

Comment: @AnT You're right, it doesn't work, just wrote that off the top of my head

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time!